# Generating function from a set of arbitrary integer values

Tags: functions

Is it possible to define a function defined in domain $\mathbb{R}$ which curves through a set of points $(n, a_n)$ where the function's local minimum and maximum between $(x_i, y_i)$ and $(x_{i+1}, y_{i+1})$ are $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$, therefore something like this doesn't pass the condition:

$$\sum^{k}_{i=1}{a_ie^{-\frac{(x-i)^2}{0.00...1}}}$$

Function's values $x<1\bigcup x>k$ are not important.

EDIT: A simple example would be a polynomial function which passes through a series of points like $f(x) = x^2-x$ which satisfies $a=(0, 2, 6)$

Comment: Some clarifications: you're saying that we're given $k$ values $a_1, \dots, a_k$, and *in addition* we're given $N$ points $(x_1, y_1), \dots, (x_N, y_N)$? Are we guaranteed that $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_N$? When you say "local minimum and maximum between $(x_i, y_i)$ and $(x_{i + 1}, y_{i + 1})$", do you just mean the minimum/maximum values that the function takes on in the interval $[x_i, x_{i + 1}]$? Are there any restrictions on the function (e.g. continuity, differentiability, etc.?)

Comment: point $(x_n, y_n)$ is $(n, a_n)$, so $x_{n-1}<x_n$, yes points are min/max values within interval $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$. The function needs to be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just use a piecewise-linear function whose graph consists of line segments from each point $(n, a_n)$ to the next point $(n + 1, a_{n + 1})$.

Comment: The function cannot be piecewise, entire domain must be represented as whole

Comment: I don't understand. If we're being precise, it makes no sense to speak of a function being piecewise or not being piecewise. It does make (a little bit of) sense to speak of a function's *definition* being piecewise. Are you saying that you in some sense want the function to be defined by "one formula"? Maybe it would help if you added some context explaining why you want this function?

Comment: I meant the function cannot be defined piecewise, sorry.

Comment: The thing is, that's not too well-defined. Any piecewise definition can be rephrased as a single (uglier) formula.